# Selecting varchar values from a column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm working on SQL 2008 and have a table with 1000's of codes in it - a sample would be:

```
D37
D37.0
D38
D38.0
D39
D39.0
D3A
D3A.0
D40
```

What I need to do is select the values between `D37` and `D40`. However, I do not want the D3A values (or D3B or D3C for that matter). I have tried the following:

```
SELECT Code
FROM Table
WHERE Code BETWEEN 'D37' AND 'D40'
```

However, this get all the codes listed above, including the `D3A` codes.

Is there a way to exclude the codes that do not fall in the 37-40 range?

Comment: 'D3A' is between 'D37' and 'D40', it is usual it appears in results.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain why you think it shouldn't be between D37 and D40?  It should be alphabetically and hexadecimally...

Comment: @MattFellows, hexadecimally? no one talks about hexadecimale in question. Just about varchar.

Comment: I guess I'm looking more at the numerical portion of the code - the 37 and don't consider A to be between 37 and 40.

Comment: Then you should talk about this condition in your question. Perhaps `and isnumeric( left(code,2))=1 and len(code)=3` in your `where` clause can helps.

Comment: This is yet another example of why you only store a single item per column. A better design would have split the letter, number and decimal portion of this "code" into three columns.  You could display all three together, yet query each part separately.

Comment: @danihp No - indeed no one does mention Hexadecimal - but I was attempting to think of a reason that the OP would not think D3A should not be between D37 and D40.  Is there something wrong with this? Are VARCHAR columns inherently unable to store hexadecimal values?

Comment: @MattFellows, sorry, my mistake, I thinked yours first comment was I reply to my own. Be happy! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the single-letter convention is followed throughout, and there aren't any more weird characters than shown in the data, you can do this:

```
WITH cte AS (
    [MyColumn]
  , SELECT SUBSTRING([MyColumn],2,LEN([MyColumn)-1) AS Code
  FROM MyTable
  WHERE ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING([MyColumn],2,LEN([MyColumn)-1)=1
)
SELECT [MyColumn]
FROM cte
WHERE CAST(Code AS float) BETWEEN 37 AND 40
```

Answer (score 0):

It's messy, but this should do what you are asking.

SELECT code
from Mytable
where 
ISNUMERIC( SUBSTRING(code, 2, (len(code)) ) ) > 0
and convert(float, SUBSTRING(code, 2, (len(code))) ) between 37 and 40

Comment: I think you'll get conversion errors, which is why I did a cte in my answer, to make a two-step process.   Yours will try to convert "3A" to a float.

Comment: Is this even valid SQL?

Comment: That's why the ISNUMERIC check is there.  I've tried it on the sample data that was posted and it works fine.

Comment: Heh, yes, Zoff. I've run it in SSMS and it works fine.